# sort не работает с std::bind

Tags: c++, visual-studio, сортировка, bind

Почему код не работает, если вместо 3 вставить число меньше 6. И как это можно исправить?
Код должен сортировать вектор с помощью функтора std::greater, который должен применять 1 параметр. Сделать это нужно с помощью std::bind.

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
static void PrintVector(const std::vector<T> &v)
{
    for (auto iterator = v.begin(); iterator != v.end(); ++iterator)
    {
        std::cout << *iterator << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{       
    vector<int> v = { 1, 8, 7, 4, 3, 6, 2, 5 };
    PrintVector(v);
    auto greater_binded = bind(greater<int>(), placeholders::_1, 3);
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), greater_binded);
    PrintVector(v);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Почему код не работает...?" А где в вашем вопросе осмысленное описание того, что этот код должен делать вообще? Никакого вменяемого объяснения из самого кода извлечь не удается - он бессмыслен.

Answer (score 5):

Алгоритм `std::sort` предполагает наличие *strict weak ordering* для функций сравнения (25.4 Sorting and related operations)

> 3 For all algorithms that take Compare, there is a version that uses
>   operator< instead. That is, comp(*i, *j) != false defaults to *i < *j
>   != false. **For algorithms other than those described in 25.4.3 to
>   work correctly, comp has to induce a *strict weak ordering* on the
>   values.**

Это значит, что не допускается, что если `comp( a, b )` есть true, то одновременно и `comp( b, a )` также true.

Если вы хотите разбить массив на партиции, то используйте стандартный алгоритм `std::partition`. Например,

```
std::partition( v.begin(), v.end(), greater_binded );
```

Если необходимо, то затем каждую партицию можно отсортировать отдельно.

Comment: Кажется, читал пару дней назад об этом на google groups. И кажется это были Вы :)

Comment: @isnullxbh На google я в основном участвую на форумах isocpp.org по обсуждению C++ стандарта.

Answer (score 2):

А что этот код должен делать? `std::sort` принимает бинарный предикат. Что-то с чем можно сделать так:

```
if(pred(x, y)){
   //...
}
```

Вы же взяли бинарный предикат `greater` и забиндили у него один аргумент. По идее теперь он принимает только один аргумент. Хотя на самом деле [не специфицировано](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/?kw=bind) что там возвращает `std::bind`([пример](http://ideone.com/xvHrv4))

Короче, код хоть и компилируется, но работать в таком виде правильно не будет. Потому что предикат `greater_binded` работает только с одним аргументом, а для сортировки нужно сравнивать два элемента.

В этом легко убедится, если заменить `std::bind` на старый добрый `std::bind2nd`. Ошибка выполнения сразу превратится в ошибку компиляции:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
static void PrintVector(const std::vector<T> &v)
{
    for (auto iterator = v.begin(); iterator != v.end(); ++iterator)
    {
        std::cout << *iterator << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{       
    vector<int> v = { 1, 8, 7, 4, 3, 6, 2, 5 };
    PrintVector(v);
    auto greater_binded = bind2nd(greater<int>(), 3);
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), greater_binded);
    PrintVector(v);
}
```

> h:125:23: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'std::binder2nd >'
>           { return bool(_M_comp(*__it1, *__it2)); }